# How to Scroll to the Top of an Elementor Accordion When Clicked?

Tags: accordion, elementor

I'm facing an issue with my Elementor native accordion on mobile devices. Whenever I expand or collapse an accordion section, the varying content lengths cause the page to scroll far down, making it difficult for users to navigate smoothly.

Is there a solution to automatically scroll to the top of the clicked accordion title when it is expanded?

I've been searching online for a solution to my accordion scrolling problem, but unfortunately, I haven't found much helpful information. I'm hoping that someone here might be able to provide a few lines of code that can help me resolve this issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance